# Refreshing animated tile layer without reloading maps control

Tags: bing-maps

I'm using the animated radar layer from the Bing Maps interactive SDK:
https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/weatherradarmap?toWww=1&redig=40890DB2E2C449AC91DAD6CD69209931

I understand how the tile layers are getting assigned. How could I modify that so that the tile layers were refreshed on an interval (say every 15 minutes) without reloading the entire page (meaning without reloading the maps control)?

So far I've pulled out the `tileSource` loop into its own function:

```
 function addRadarLayer() {
                // alert to mark time when radar data was loaded or refreshed
                // var d = new Date();
                // alert("Updating radar " + d.toLocaleTimeString());
                // alert (map.layers.length);

                for (var i = 0; i < timestamps.length; i++) {
                    var tileSource = new Microsoft.Maps.TileSource({
                        uriConstructor: urlTemplate.replace('{timestamp}', timestamps[i])
                    });
                    tileSources.push(tileSource);
                };


                if (map.layers.length>0) {
                    // alert('clear layer');
                    // map.layers.clear();
                    // alert(map.layers.length);
                    //alert('add layer')
                    map.layers[0].setOptions({ mercator: tileSources, frameRate: 500 });
                } else {
                    var animatedLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.AnimatedTileLayer({ mercator: tileSources, frameRate: 500 });
                    map.layers.insert(animatedLayer);
                    //alert('New tiles');
                };
            };
```

then I call that function directly and then using `setInterval`

```
                addRadarLayer();

                window.setInterval(function () {
                    addRadarLayer();
                    }, 1000 * 60 * 15); // repeat forever, polling every 15 minutes

            };
```

But after some time I can see the page no longer refreshing. If I refresh the browser all is OK, but (again) that reloads the map control which is not what I really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refresh the tile source, add a random query string parameter to the URL like

`?r=1234` and change the value (1234) on each refresh. This should by pass the local cache which is root cause of your issue.

Comment: Thank you! Local caching never occurred to me.